# css: top in % measure not working in firefox , but working perftcly fine in chrome

Tags: css

Below code will produce a centered circle .

In Chrome circle is displaced by 10% from top.
But In Firefox it is not. Why

```css
.game 
{
        height: 40vw;
        width: 40vw;
        background-color: #333;
        border-radius: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        margin:0 auto;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 1.6vw #333;
        top:10%;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="game.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="game">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output in Chrome:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x097C.png)

Output in Firefox:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNJGv.png)

Comment: what firefox version did u use? cuz it's working normally here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set `body` and `html` in your css?

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A) Insert this code to style:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.game {
    height: 40vw;
    width: 40vw;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1.6vw #333;
    top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="game"></div>
```

Comment: @Pete , what is parent here?

Answer (score -2):

make sure your Firefox tab window is zoom out.